# Which module creates the "Article" and "Basic page" content types?

Tags: 8, entities

By Default we have two content types: *Article* and *Basic page*.

Which module creates those content types?

Comment: Those two content types are created by the Standard installation profile you chose when installing Drupal.

Comment: I found Node Entity and NodeType under core Node module. If it is a part of install then they should be written in install file or somethjing like that. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Wim Mostrey was right.

In Drupal 7, the default configuration for modules (e.g. content types, field configuration, views) required custom PHP code to install and keep updated. In Drupal 8, these are stored with the configuration system in plain text YAML files, for example [core/profiles/standard/config/install/node.type.article.yml](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!profiles!standard!config!install!node.type.article.yml/8.2.x).

#### References

- [Include default configuration in your Drupal 8 module](https://www.drupal.org/node/2087879)